# tagName jquery not work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive read a lot of posts but no success

I have

```
<h2 id="h2LoginCaptcha">Login</h2>
```

In jquery I try to read the tagName property like this :

```
var randomElement = $('#' + id1);
        var randomNumber = 9999;

        if(randomElement['0'].tagName == "H2"){
                   ...
                }
```

it works like a charm in Chrome, Firefox and Opera
But does not work in IE. I got ***Unable to get value of property tagName....***

A help how to read tagName 'H2' please

Comment: Take a look at the console,which errors does it throw?

Comment: Unable to get value of property tagName....

Comment: Does it work in compatibility mode?

Comment: no. it does not work in compatib. mode

Comment: did you tried: ``$(randomElement).prop("tagName");``??

Comment: Why are you testing the tag name in the first place? Which problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: got undefinied when using .prop("tagName")

Comment: @Al2x That probably means the element isn't found. You need to provide more of a context for this code

Comment: What is the value of `id1` ?

Comment: Try using [0] instead of ['0']

Comment: id1 is <h2 id="h2LoginCaptcha">Login</h2>

Comment: The hole string or just the value of `id`?

Comment: sorry. id1 is h2LoginCaptcha

Comment: Again, what are you trying to accomplish with this code? Why are you testing which tag name the element has? The error message implicates that the element does not exist.

Comment: man, Im trying to get into the IF condition. please see my print screen. When I compile the code I got error message when reading the ...tagName

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. **Why** are you testing for the tag name of the element? Can it be that the ID is applied to different elements? If your HTML is always `<h2 id="h2LoginCaptcha">Login</h2>`, then the tag name will always be `H2`, so why test for it?

Comment: sorry. I need to compare if is H2 element. the id can be applied to different elements

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID at the same time in the page?

Comment: @Al2x What you have **should** work, so please post a jsFiddle with the code that doesn't work in IE9. Otherwise this is not reproducible

Comment: theres another way to read from <h2/> tag the tagName regarding the IE compatibility ?

Comment: If the ID can be applied to different elements, I assume it can also be applied to *no* element at all. Maybe the code that is supposed to add the ID or generates the element doesn't run in IE.

Comment: @Al2x: You are missing the point. The problem is not that the tag name cannot be read. The problem is that element isn't found, which very likely means that it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jquery already, try using `is`

```
if (randomElement.is('h2'))
```

Comment: Ive tried with randomElement.tagName but the same error

Comment: obviously thought to answer this but "*works like a charm in other broswers*" got me stumped `;)`

Comment: Arrays are just objects. Every property name is converted to a string anyway. Using a number instead of a string won't make a difference.

Comment: IN console I got always false when using .is('h2')

Comment: @FelixKling What is that in response to? No one's even addressing that part of the code

Comment: @Ian: It was in response to Daniel's original post, which he edited within the grace period.